# Tcl procedure cannot read variable passed in by another procedure

Tags: tcl

I have a Tcl procedure that wraps around another procedure and passes it some arguments, like so:

```
proc OuterProc {
  ...some code here...
  InnerProc $a $b
}

proc InnerProc { a, b } {
  set someVar1 [split $a]
  set someVar2 [split $b]
  ...error: cannot read variable a or b
}
```

Why can't the `InnerProc` see the 2 arguments being passed in?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem as shown in the question, is you have a comma in your argument list. Note that Tcl generally uses whitespace to separate arguments, not commas.

```
proc OuterProc {} {
    set x foo
    set y bar
    InnerProc $x $y
}
proc InnerProc {a b} {
    puts "a=$a"
    puts "b=$b"
}
OuterProc
```

produces

```
a=foo
b=bar
```

I've used different variable names in the OuterProc procedure to demonstrate that is does not matter what your local variable *names* are, Tcl will pass the *values* to the next proc.

If that is not your problem, then you need to show us more specifically what your real code is.

Comment: @czchlong, to say that "Tcl generally uses whitespace to separate arguments" is oversimplification.  In fact, the `proc` command interprets its second argument as *a list,* and the form `{a b}` is just a common way to write a list literal in a Tcl script to get a list consisting of the two strings -- `a` and `b`.

Comment: In fact `proc x {a, b} {}` is a valid list of arguments. You'd just need to brace the variable name: `puts "${a,} and $b"`